# PING sensor on RPI, start counting when less than 40cm?

Tags: c, timer, count, raspberry-pi, ping

I have a PING sensor (HC-SR04) hooked up to my RPI. I want it to start counting when the sensor sees less than 40 cm. It should stop counting again when the sensor again sees less than 40 cm, print out the time and start counting again.
How can I do this?
This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <wiringPi.h>

#define TRUE 1

#define TRIG 5
#define ECHO 6

void setup() {
    wiringPiSetup();
    pinMode(TRIG, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(ECHO, INPUT);

    //TRIG pin must start LOW
    digitalWrite(TRIG, LOW);
    delay(30);
}

int getCM() {
    //Send trig pulse
    digitalWrite(TRIG, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(20);
    digitalWrite(TRIG, LOW);

    //Wait for echo start
    while(digitalRead(ECHO) == LOW);

    //Wait for echo end
    long startTime = micros();
    while(digitalRead(ECHO) == HIGH);
    long travelTime = micros() - startTime;

    //Get distance in cm
    int distance = travelTime / 58;

    return distance;
}

int i;

int main(void) {
    setup();

    while (1)
    {
            printf("Distance: %dcm\n", getCM());
            delay(250);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which granularity do you need for time?

Comment: Do you mean like minuts and seconds and such?
Then I need seconds and milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

The code doesn't measure the distance. It only measures the duration of the reflected signal. To get the distance you need to measure the delay between the beginning of ping, and the beginning of echo:

```
    startTime = micros();

    digitalWrite(TRIG, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(20);
    digitalWrite(TRIG, LOW);

    //Wait for echo start
    while(digitalRead(ECHO) == LOW);
    long travelTime = micros() - startTime;
```

Of course, this is just a skeleton: you need to debounce the echo to guard yourself against background noises and other glitches.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? I am getting the distance with my code? It works just fine for measuring distance